# Full disk encryption configuration

Tags: encryption, bitlocker

I'm buying a new Windows computer and I want to configure it to be secure. I want to use full disk encryption. My question is will my SSD work on a different computer in case my computer breaks. Also, should I use TPM, are there any negative things about it? Also, how easy is it to brute force the encrypted SSD in case someone tries to access it?

Encryption will not help me if my computer gets stolen while sleeping, not fully powered down, is that right? So what should I do if I keep it in sleep mode most of the time, or even just locked? Also how to be safe from attacks from lets say USB drives when in Windows lock mode?

Thank you!

Comment: What encryption are you using, the current question is a little broad and unclear - try rephrasing your question to be more about TPM and SSD encryption - not all disk encryption requires TPM. The second set of question should be in their own question, but also need some more focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea - FDE is a sensible thing to use if you have a mobile device with any sort of sensitive data on it. Unless you have very specific requirements, I'd say the easiest thing is to just use the FDE that comes with your operating system, which for Windows means Bitlocker.

To answer your questions in turn:

### Will my SSD work on a different computer?

It depends on the FDE method you use. If you use a TPM, then no.
However, most FDE systems, including TPM-based ones, have some way to take a backup of the key that you can use in such an emergency. You probably should do this anyway. (Of course, you have to secure the backup carefully.)

### Should I use a TPM?

The TPM module adds another thing you have to trust, which is not ideal, but you are already trusting both the laptop and the OS manufacturer, so that's not a huge deal normally.

And on the plus side, the TPM means you don't have to remember another good password or PIN code.

### Can it be brute forced?

Again, depends on the FDE method you use, but any FDE vendor who is not entirely stupid will use an algorithm that can not be practically brute forced. Bitlocker, for example, is based on AES, and so is very safe.

### Will this help me if my machine is sleeping instead of powered off?

No, but it is not meant to. FDE is meant to protect against what is called an offline attack, which is where the bad guy connects your disk to another computer (or boots your computer from a  USB stick, which is the same thing.) While the computer is turned on or sleeping, it is the OS's job to protect your data - which modern OSes will do very effectively.

(Getting the key out of RAM while the device is powered on is theoretically possible but very difficult in practice. If you are concerned about an attacker with those sorts of resources then you have lots of more pressing problems to worry about.)

Comment: Also how to be safe from attacks from lets say USB drives when in Windows lock mode? I've seen videos where they just put USB drives when in user selection window and take control. How to be secure from this? One way would be to just disable all USB's at lock/log off. And the only thing they could do then is to restart the computer and see that it is encrypted with a password?

Comment: You should make sure that your operating system is set up not to run programs automatically when a USB stick is inserted. (all modern operating systems have this feature turned off out of the box, so your new computer will be OK).

Answer (score 1):

> will my SSD work on a different computer in case my computer breaks.

Yes. Everything that is required to decrypt the drive and boot the OS is contained on the drive itself. Windows my not work correctly if you change the underlying hardware but as far as the encryption goes it makes no difference.

> how easy is it to brute force the encrypted SSD in case someone tries to access it?

This depends on the encryption algorithm used. AES would take trillions of years to brute force because there are so many possible key combinations. There are plenty of resources available to assert this. If you don't want to go into the methematics of it then a pragmatic way of looking at it is that [not even the FBI can break AES.](http://news.techworld.com/security/3228701/fbi-hackers-fail-to-crack-truecrypt/)

> Encryption will not help me if my computer gets stolen while sleeping, not fully powered down, is that right?

Your drive is either encrypted and unusable or decrypted and usable. When your comuter is running the drive must be decrypted and is therefor in a vulnerable position. If you leave your machine powered on then someone can take the encryption key from RAM and decrypt the drive later.

> So what should I do if I keep it in sleep mode most of the time, or even just locked?

This is a problem of security vs usability. You need to decide for your self how valuable your data is and in what situations it is best to power off instead of sleep.

One piece of advice is to use an open source encryption tool. Bitlocker is propitiatory which means that only the Microsoft has access to the source code. If they deliberately plant a backdoor or mess up the encryption implementation then no one outside Microsoft would know or be able to fix it.

An open source tool like Truecrypt allows anyone to download and view the source code. This means that independent 3rd parties can verify that there are no backdoors or serious bugs.

Comment: In order for it to take trillions of years to break AES, you need a strong password. Here is a good guide on how to create a strong password: https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2014/03/choosing_secure_1.html